# windows 8.1 access to wifi without signing in

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1, lock-screen

On my lock-screen, there is a networks icon (The one with the little white bars that represent the strength of a wifi signal) and if I click on it, I can change whether my laptop is connected to wifi and I also have access to toggle 'airplane mode' on and off.

I removed all the apps from the lock screen settings, but this seems to be the default. **Is there a way to remove the possibility of changing networking settings before one is signed in?** After all, I thought the whole point of a machine being 'locked' is to prevent unauthorized users from changing the state of the said machine.

If this persists, then I'll be hoping for a good registry hack..

I'm new to Windows 8.1, so go easy on me :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a domain, use Group Policy to push this setting. If not, open local policy editor (gpedit.msc) and browse out to this setting.

Computer Configuration | Administrative Templates | System | Logon --> Do not display network selection UI

When you've set the change, run gpupdate /force from the cmd prompt then restart the PC, the wifi indicator should be gone!

Comment: I tried searching for local policy editor and also entering gpedit.msc into the 'run' interface, but the program cannot be located. Is this editor supposed to be part of win 8.1?

Comment: Ahh, must have a home edition. Here, click on 'download group policy installer' on this page. http://www.askvg.com/how-to-enable-group-policy-editor-gpedit-msc-in-windows-7-home-premium-home-basic-and-starter-editions/

Comment: Yep, and I only realized that now. Oddly enough the bit about home edition is not revealed to me through pc info nor through systeminfo in cmd.. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you launch powershell and type 'get-wmiobject win32_operatingsystem | select-object -property caption' you'll see the full version name of your os.

Comment: All it gives me is "Microsoft Windows 8.1". I suppose if the policy editor is not present, then I most likely have home edition.

Comment: Sorry man I think you need to run that installer to turn on Group Policy Editor. If it works mark this as the answer so other people will know what to do.